# How to avoid shuffling during join?

Tags: apache-spark

I have two PB scale dataframes that I am joining, I already know the key I am joining by, is there a way to make each worker only read the data for the keys it needs so that shuffle can be avoided?

For example can I have a folder structure like

```
key1-keyN/
    file1
    file2
    .....

keyN-key2N/
    file1
    file2
    .....
```

that way each worker will already have the data for the key it is assigned?

Or is there a hadoop map side join equivalent such that I can provide a globally sorted file by key and make joining easier.

Answer (score 0):

It Is possible to avoid a shuffle when a previous transformation has already partitioned the data according to the same partitioner => If **two rdd** have the **same partitioner**, the join will **not cause a shuffle**.